# Copy bitmap issue

Tags: android, bitmap

I've got a question to ask. I just want to add a text to a bitmap in following code. when I debug to `Bitmap bmp = bmp1.copy(bmp1.getConfig(), true);` everything worked fine in watch window I can see width and height with 640 and 480.

but after excute the copy method it returns the Bitmap to bmp, but the width and height of bmp is -1 and -1, and it couldn't add the text. could some guys told me why and how to fix the problem. thanks a lot

```
    String strPath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    String strFileNameIn="aaa.jpg";
    File inFile=new File(strPath+File.separator+strFileNameIn); 
    try {
        if (inFile.exists()) {
    FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(inFile);
    BitmapDrawable bmpDraw = new BitmapDrawable(inStream);
        Bitmap bmp1 = bmpDraw.getBitmap();
    Bitmap bmp = bmp1.copy(bmp1.getConfig(), true);

    Canvas cv = new Canvas(bmp);
    SimpleDateFormat sDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String strText = sDateFormat.format(new Date());
        Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.RED);

    cv.drawText(strText, 0, 0, p);
    cv.save(Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
    cv.restore();
    }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          String strMsg = e.getMessage();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a bitmap more easily with bitmapfactory.

How about this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("your file");
if (bitmap != null) {
    Paint p = new Paint();
    Canvas cv = new Canvas();
    cv.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, p);
    SimpleDateFormat sDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String strText = sDateFormat.format(new Date());
    p.setColor(Color.RED);

    cv.drawText(strText, 0, 0, p);
    cv.save(Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
    cv.restore();
}
```

Comment: hi Tamas. Thanks for your reply. I've tired your suggestion, the decodeFile method return the Bitmap object but it meets the question I described earlier -1,-1 of width and height. Is it my image question? but i can view it properly. god... any suggestions?

Comment: Hi all. Thanks for view my thread. I finally find out the problem out. Actually all things worked fine, and the text is drawn on the photo but I can not see, because I set the start position (0,0) is just the left-bottom of the text(or text rectangle ), it is just out of the bound of the current image.